# RabbitMQ. Client cannot publish message to queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

[image]
I am using Rabbimq 3.8.8 on cluster with 3 Nodes
I have 1 **publisher** publish event with routing key is: *routingkey1*. Event is going to route to 2 Quorum Queue (**Queue A** and **Queue B**) and two consumer (use .NET). I set publiser wait confirm for 10 seconds.
*After a period of stable running, the system have a problem:*
The message was sent but there was only **Queue A** received it. Publisher alyways confirm return false after long time waiting.
I've tried everything but still can't send the message to **Queue A**. But when I sent a message on the management page, it was successful.
I ended up having to delete the **Queue B** and redeclare. Then **Queue B** works again normally
Thanks to everyone for help!